# Unexpected token error at table alias using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring hibernate.

My code is as below:

```
String hql = "select a.candidate_id_fk, count(*) from Answers a , Question b where a.question_id_fk = b.id"+""
            +"and a.answer=b.correct_answer group by a.candidate_id_fk";

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
List list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
```

> Error:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
>    unexpected token: a

Comment: There probably should be a whitespace where you write `""` -> `" "`.

Comment: As mentioned luk2302, it looks like the resulting hql has a missing space. You may print the `hql` variable to check the result, e.g. by using `System.out.println(hql);` and checking the console.

Comment: Thanks luk2302 and Jaime....it was a missing space